# Java Swing Library To Display Zip/Jar In A Tree

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a Swing GUI that will let me drag a jar onto it and display the contents as a tree.

I could extend JTree myself and use ZipFile but I would rather use a library instead as it is the sort of thing that is likely to have lots of little issues that other people have already solved.

Are there any Swing libraries that can do this? I looked at the JIDE Common layer and SwingX but didn't see anything.

I imagine that Netbeans or eclipse frameworks could do this but I would rather look for Swing libraries first before entertaining them.

Comment: Perhaps you could unzip the file into a temporary directory, then use a component which views file hierarchies.  I'm sure there's a widget for that in JIDE or SwingX or something similar.

Comment: On Mac OS X, right-click the JAR and choose "Open With" `Archive Utility.app`.

Comment: @trashgod what has that got to do with me building my own Swing GUI??

Comment: @JoeCoder The 'widget' is JTree from the JDK and as I mentioned in my question I can use a ZipFile to create this myself (without the need to extract to a temp. dir). I am looking for a library that encapsulates all of this already.

Comment: My comment implements @JoeCoder's first suggestion; anything like that on your OS?

Comment: @trashgod Archive Utility.app isn't a Java Swing library! How am I supposed to integrate it into my Swing application?

Comment: I didn't say it was; I've proposed a Swing approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18904005/230513).